# sed: print all lines THROUGH the LAST match of pattern A, then print ONLY lines that match pattern B

Tags: shell, perl, awk, sed, scripting

Esteemed colleagues...

I generate log files of several thousand lines of the form:

```
a
b
X
d
X
e
b
g
Y
a
Y
d
```

For example, I would like the output of my script to print all lines THROUGH the last match of "^X" and then print only matches of "^Y".  Desired output for above:

```
a
b
X
d
X
Y
Y
```

"X" will always appear, but "Y" may not.  In cases where "Y" does not appear, I *believe* that the last "X" will be on the last line of the file.

It was quite difficult to do this with "sed", although that's what I've been trying. I use "tac" to flip the line order so I can delete anything not matching "^Y" through the *FIRST* match of "^X". Because I don't use "-n", after that first match of "^X", all lines are echoed.  I just use "tac" again to flip it around and put it in a file.

This *seems* to work...

```
tac /path/to/logfile | \
sed -e '1,/^X/ { /^Y/!d }' | \
tac > /output/path/logfile.processed
```

No...?

PS: Is "tac" commonly available on all Linux?

Comment: Is it possible that there is a `Y` between two `X` lines?

Comment: What should be output if there is no X in the input?

Comment: @kvantour: No. There should never be an "X" there, but I believe that rule is secondary to the need to find the LAST "X".

Comment: @EdMorton: There will always be a "X" in the input. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

without `tac`, a double-pass approach with `awk`

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{if(/^X$/) lx=NR; next} FNR<=lx || /^Y$/' file{,}

a
b
X
d
X
Y
Y
```

mark the last index of `X` and print all before that index and other matching pattern.

Comment: If a platform has "sed", but not "awk", I'd be surprised.  Both "awk" and "tac" are in "/usr/bin" on some platforms, but "sed" is in "/bin". I'm not sure if it's riskier to depend on "tac" or "awk"...  Thanks for your help.  I like your short answer...

Comment: If a platform is POSIX, it will have `awk`

Comment: @LanceE.T.Compte it's riskier to depend on tac than awk. Over the past 35 years or so Ive used many machines that didn't have tac but none that didn't have some flavor of awk.

Answer (score 2):

To avoid reading twice, you could use a `perl`:

```
$ perl -0777 -lnE 'say $1 while (/(\A[\s\S]*^X$|^Y$)/gm)' file
a
b
X
d
X
Y
Y
```

Or, with `sed` and common utilities:

```
$ sed_cmd=$(printf "1,%sp; /^Y/p" $(cat -n file | sed -nE 's/^[[:space:]]*([[:digit:]][[:digit:]]*)[[:space:]]*X/\1/p' | tail -n 1))
$ sed -nE "$sed_cmd" file
# same output
```

Comment: How does your "sed" improve on mine, other than to get rid of "tac"? It seems you're finding the line number of the last match...

Comment: Also can use '.' instead of \s\S by adding the s modifier: perl -0777 -nE 'say $1 while (/(^.*^X$|^Y$)/gms)' file

Comment: *How does your "sed" improve on mine, other than to get rid of "tac"?* That is the improvement. `tac` is not that common on non Linux platforms, but the `sed` I have there is POSIX compliant. Indeed, the pipeline with `cat` is to determine the line number of the last `X`

Answer (score 0):

Here's a somewhat more logically explicit version using Perl.

```
perl -MList::Util=max -lnE '
    $lines{$.} = $_; 
    eof || next; 
    $last_match = max grep {$lines{$_} =~ /^X/} keys %lines;
    say for @lines{1 .. $last_match};
    say for grep {$_ =~ /^Y/} @lines{$last_match .. $.};
' /path/to/logfile
```

Comment: I do find this kind of brute force approach is quite readable/maintainable. I'm already worried about portability since I need to run on many different flavors of Linux. Isn't list::util in coremodules now?

Comment: Yes, `List::Util` is a core module.